# Opencart Import Wishlist Data

Tags: mysql, opencart

Opencart 1.5.5.1 (Mijoshop 2.4.4)

I am trying to import wishlist data directly into the MySQL database but it keeps getting deleted.

If I go to the customer table in phpMyAdmin I can edit a specific customer. I add 1 product to the column 'wishlist' for example:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:3:"263";}
```

If I then login as that customer via Opencart admin and try to access their wishlist there is nothing there. When I go back to phpMyAdmin the column just reads a:0:{}

Is there any way to make the import stick?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately looking into the OC 1.5.5.1 and the wishlist controller as well as customer model and customer library, there is nothing that would load and store some data into the `wishlist` column in customers table.

Though there is a column `wishlist` in OC 1.5.5.1 indeed, it looks like it is not used yet in this version.

Try to download the latest version of OC where this column might be already used or if not you could always add this functionality by yourself (e.g. adding method for loading and saving to the customer model as well as modifying the wishlist controller).

It is even weird that the value you have manually inserted into this column in DB is deleted as there is no update of customer data happening as well as nor wishlist data deleting...